# How to encrypt a small text using openssl with a given public Key

Tags: openssl

so I want to encrypt the string `1200|2000.00` using OpenSSL with an already existing public Key.

So my text is stored in a file called 'plaintext.txt', and according to some other resources, I ran the following command.

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public.key -in plaintext.txt -out encrypted.txt
```

However, for some reason, my output was given as the following when opened in notepad...

```
歆贎帡➃嗼Ἶ毒䅂橂〕䢣࡞㢧퍈벉ᢰＢ᳒噌⚝갗滔曍䫵牛鳝辽ᆗ綍E実悖䗹輴倰و抠峤�饭䀽嘕ﰜ㝤ズ똬烧嵇诙셎쵅ᕀဍ峇贆᱕땃빸覍턴
```

And this is something that I did not expect, did I do something wrong?

Can anyone please help me with this, as I have been instructed to encrypt the data using `encrypted using openssl_public_encrypt method`.

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of the `openssl rsautl` command that you posted is raw bytes, not text.  That's why the output looks garbled when you open it in notepad.

If you want the output of `openssl rsautl` to be displayable text, you can encode the output using base64 encoding, then write the base64 encoded ciphertext to a file.  This can be done by stringing a few commands together on the command line, like so:

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey pub.key -in plaintext.txt | base64 > encrypted.txt
```

You should be able to open encrypted.txt in notepad, or view it on the command line, and see the base64 encoded ciphertext.

To decrypt the base64 encoded ciphertext, you would to the following:

```
cat encrypted.txt | base64 -d | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey priv.key
```